# How do I toggle an element's visibility during fast momentum scrolling in an iOS Phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

Using the following code on a touch overflow container works fine except during fast scrolling (quick successive flicks) and while the content is still moving from resulting "momentum."  During fast momentum scrolling, the div does not show/hide until the content slows/eases into a rest position.

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function () {
    var yDistance = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (yDistance > 300) {
        $('#div').hide();
    } else {
        $('#div').show();
    }
});
```

I have tried a 1ms timeout to place some priority in the JS stack, with no change in result.  I suspect that all rendering is diverted to momentum visuals and any JS DOM manipulation is queued.

Is there any way to ensure that this simple hide/show of a div gets priority among the scroll related rendering?